# Android convert Bitmap to Base64 string issue

Tags: android, image, bitmap, base64

i have a problem with converting Bitmap to Base64. I want to post some images from camera or gallery. When i get them as image and i must convert to base64 but when i'm getting the string and testing with http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter to see my image. Result looks very bad quality. How can i fix this pls help me ?
Here is my code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
    switch(requestCode)
    {
        case 0:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                Bundle extras = imageReturnedIntent.getExtras();
                Bitmap selectedImage = (Bitmap)extras.get("data");
                secilenImage.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
                String encodedImage;
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                try
                {
                    selectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                    byte[] b = stream.toByteArray();
                    encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    images.add(i, encodedImage);
                    Log.d("StringForCamera: ", encodedImage);
                    stream.close();
                }
                catch(IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                secilenImage.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
                secilenImage.setEnabled(false);
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                Uri imageUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                Bitmap selectedImage = null;
                String encodedImage;
                try
                {
                    selectedImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),imageUri);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayBitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    selectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayBitmapStream);
                    byte[] b = byteArrayBitmapStream.toByteArray();
                    encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                    images.add(i, encodedImage);
                    Log.d("StringForGallery: ",encodedImage);
                }
                catch(IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                secilenImage.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
                secilenImage.setEnabled(false);
            }
            break;
    }
    ++i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 (Bitmap)extras.get("data");
```

That is only a thumbnail of the image. Hence the low quality.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer. So how can i get image from camera ?
Edit: i have same problem on gallery.

Comment: Thete are hundreds of examles for getting a picture with the camera on the internet and on this site. Your problem has been reported so often. Just google for the used intent.